# Observable.fromEvent(this.handle, 'mousedown'); (left click only)

Tags: rxjs

I have the following function which is working accept i do not want to triffer the `switchMap` if the mouseDown event was a right click

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    let mousedown$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.handle, 'mousedown');
    let mousemove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
    let mouseup$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');

    let mousedrag$ = mousedown$.switchMap((event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log('mousedown :', event);
        if (event.which !== 1) {
            //   something when wrong
        }
        let startX = event.clientX;
        let startY = event.clientY;

        return mousemove$
            .map((event: MouseEvent) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.delta = {
                    x: event.clientX - startX,
                    y: event.clientY - startY
                };
            })
            .takeUntil(mouseup$);
    }).takeUntil(this.destroy$);

});
```

how can i modify `let mousedown$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.handle, 'mousedown');`  to only take `event.which === 1`

Comment: use `filter(event => event.which === 1)` before `switchMap`

Answer (score 0):

as @ShamPooSham suggested;

A filter before the switchMap did the trick.

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    let mousedown$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.handle, 'mousedown');
    let mousemove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
    let mouseup$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');

    let mousedrag$ = mousedown$.filter(event => event['which'] === 1).switchMap((event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log('mousedown :', event);
        if (event.which !== 1) {
            //   something when wrong
        }
        let startX = event.clientX;
        let startY = event.clientY;

        return mousemove$
            .map((event: MouseEvent) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.delta = {
                    x: event.clientX - startX,
                    y: event.clientY - startY
                };
            })
            .takeUntil(mouseup$);
    }).takeUntil(this.destroy$);

});
```